# Microsoft Excel - how to show data on one column based off data in another column?

Tags: excel

So I have this dataset in a separate worksheet here:

```
http://i.imgur.com/W3tEFjY.png
```

Answers to the following questions below should be in the Results worksheet, where I need to use formulas and/or functions. What would be a good formula for these questions?

*Which Regions contain 6 or more Countries?*

*Which Region has the Highest Total of Vehicle Sales in 2014?*

*Which Regions have more Total Vehicle Sales in 2013 than in 2014?*

Help greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Its better if you first try yourself and then go for any help , it sounds like you have just outsourcing your homework. 

please check the link and get a help yourself
http://www.excel-easy.com/basics.html

Comment: I have tried it myself. These are the only questions I can't seem to get. I did everything else through research and studying the formulas.

Comment: @Shiro - Include your unsuccessful attempts in the question, it will increase your chances that people help you.

Answer (score 0):

For these you need to have a look at the **VLOOKUP** formula on Excel. 
thats the only formula by which you can get such kind of stuff done easily,

```
VLOOKUP( value, table, index_number, [not_exact_match] )
```

for more help and examples on this formula please see
http://www.globaliconnect.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=100:vlookup-function-in-excel&catid=78&Itemid=474